# Changing scope in directive link function

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set a scope value from a link function inside a directive, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am basically trying to set a scope value when the user changes a date picker field as below...

```
app.directive('searchForm', function() {
return{
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',  
    templateUrl: "/app/views/sales/search/search-form.html",
    link: function(element,attrs,scope){
        $('.checkIn').datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            onSelect: function(date){
            var selectedDate = new Date(date);
            var msecsInADay = 86400000;
            var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

            $(".checkOut").datepicker( "option", "minDate", endDate );
            $(".checkOut").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", '+2y' );
            $('.checkOut').attr('disabled', false);
            if($('.checkOut').val()){
                $('.numNights').val(($('.checkOut').datepicker('getDate') - $(this).datepicker('getDate'))/1000/60/60/24);
            }
            }
        });


        $('.checkOut').datepicker({
            onSelect :function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.search.nights = "Test";
                });
            }
        });             
    }
};
```

});

I have also tried `scope.$apply()` but this does not work either.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "link" function has wrong signature. It should be:

```
function link (scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }
```

See **Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM** section in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Or even better this [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-).